# Twitter Timestamp out of bounds?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I get this error when trying to post a tweet to twitter.

```
 [request] => /1/statuses/update_with_media.json [error] => Timestamp out of bounds
```

This script worked fine till I had issues with my server and they fixed it. I'm thinking it reset the time zone, so that's why I'm having this issue? What's Twitter's servers time zone set to so I can set mine accordingly in WHM?

Does anyone have another other ideas?

Comment: Make sure that the code you're using is converting your local time to GMT before converting to epoch time in seconds. Also ensure that your system clock is accurate and not running behind or ahead.

Comment: Also, if you have synced the local machine time and twitter is still not liking it by returning the same error code, it might (vaguely) mean that the 'Authorization' header is incorrectly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your server's time. You don't have to deal with epoch time conversions etc. In some API's like Twitter or AWS, not adjusted system time causes errors like this.